# return data from another python file that's constantly updating

Tags: python, variables

I have a python file that is taking websocket data and constantly updating a giant list. It updates somewhere between 2 to 10 times a second. This file runs constantly.

I want to be able to call that list from a different file so this file can process that data and do something else with it.

Basically file 1 is a worker that keeps the current state in a list, I need to be able to get this state from file 2.

I have 2 questions:
Is there any way of doing this easily? I guess the most obvious answers are storing the list in a file or a DB, which leads me to my second question;

Given that the list is updating somewhere between 2 and 10 times a second, which would be better? a file or a db? can these IO functions handle these types of update speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB is the best bet for your use case

1. This gives the flexibility to know which part of data you have already processed by having a status flag.
2. Persistence data (you can also have data replication)
3. You can scale easily if in future your applications pulls more and more data

2 -10 times is a good use case for heavy write application with DB as you will gather tons of data in short duration.

Comment: thanks mate, going with sqlite3 - seems like it would offer the best performance.